# Scheduled Task for script vs Direct Execute: issues

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, wmi, scheduled-tasks, wbem

I have a VBscript file which connects to remote computers over our network and initiates a WBEM-Scripting method.  I can open a CMD console using the credentials for a domain user account which has local admin rights on all of our desktop computers, and the script performs as desired.

I created a scheduled task on a Windows Server 2003 member server which runs the same script file using the same credentials, but it fails to connect to the WMI provider on remote computers.

The desktops are all Windows 7 SP1 and the domain is Windows Server 2008 level (forest and domain).

The domain user account was added to the local administrators group on the server, and was granted "Logon as a service" rights via Group Policy.

Question: Is there something else I'm missing that could be causing the scheduled task to fail while the interactive execution works fine?

Comment: NTLM auth not happening without explicit login?

Comment: @Skatterbrainz, Is the WMI connection failure due to insufficient permissions, or does the connection not even get established? Can you post the script?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem happening (scripts do not run as schedule tasks but, executable files do). You can get around this by doing the following:

There is a **Start in (Optional)** text box below the **Program/Script** text box on the property page for the Actions Tab. Fill it to include the path of your script So if your script is at c:\users\user\desktop\script.vbs, the text boxes will look like this:

**Program/Script:**
c:\users\user\desktop\script.vbs

**Add Arguments (Optional)**

**Start in (Optional)** c:\users\user\desktop